# Where would I find and how would I fix my .classpath file

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, classpath, assets

I was trying to get my eclipse java project to compile with assets. I read that I needed to fiddle with the buildpath.  I tried that, but I broke my program.  It no longer compiles. I read another page that said I need to fix me .classpath file; however I cannot find that file.

How could I fix my project or find that file?

Also once I find it does anyone have any advice for what to do with it?

If more information is needed, I can provide it.

EDIT:  Adding the src folder (which contains my code) is what gives me the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each Java Project in the workspace has a .classpath file. Things like the Package Explorer do not normally show you this file because you can make most changes to it using the 'Java Build Path' page of the Project Properties.

Note: On macOS and Linux files with names starting with '.' are considered hidden and are not normally shown.

You can configure Package Explorer to show these files by clicking the View Menu (the small triangle at the top right of the view). Choose 'Filters...' and turn off the '.* resources' files.

Comment: Okay, this is where the file is.  I cannot do what you are suggesting to open the hidden folder (due to my use of a limited school computer), but I did find it.  I also am unsure of what to do once I figure out how to open it, but I may or may not make another question.

Answer (score -1):

You can find your .classpath file in the root of your workspace folder.  For example if you created your Eclipse workspace in C:\workspace then you should find your classpath file at C:\workspace.classpath

Comment: I don't see the file.  I am (unfortunately) using a mac (it is a school computer).  I do not see the file.  Is it somewhere else?  is it invisible?  How would I make it visible.

Comment: This is not correct. There is a .classpath in each Java Project in the workspace.

Comment: @greg-449 I still cannot find the file.

Comment: @Darokrithia The file is normally hidden, see my answer.